# How do I wrap JSON with square brackets in R language?

Tags: r

I have a nested JSON as follows and I would like to wrap it with square brackets and return it. How could I achieve it in R with ease?
Input:

```
"{
    "info": {
        "val": 0.1885,
        "id": 1
    }
}, {
    "info": {
        "val": 1.3599,
        "id": 2
    }
}"
```

Output:

```
[{
    "info": {
        "val": 0.1885,
        "id": 1
    }
}, {
    "info": {
        "val": 1.3599,
        "id": 2
    }
}]
```

Thank you

Comment: What is your input exactly? Is that a string in R? do you have a list? How are you converting to JSON? It doesn't seem like it would even be valid JSON without the brackets.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I updated it. I get it in form of a string. I am using jsonlite to JSON function to convert to JSON.

Comment: Well, what you posted isn't a valid string in R so i'm still not sure how you are importing that. But if you just need to add braces to a string, you can do that with `paste0()` For example `paste0("[", x, "]")`.

Comment: Actually your solution of `paste0` works perfectly. That is what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you found the solution for this, but the following should work:

```
wrap_json <- function(x) {
  return(paste0("[", x, "]"))
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks I did get the answer from the comments of my question. I'll accept this as the answer as it can be helpful to others.